# Force git to run post-receive hook, even if everything is "up-to-date"

Tags: git

How do I force `git` to run a `post-receive` hook on a server even if I don't have a new commit to push?

### Background

I use git to automatically deploy a website to a server. I have a bare repo in a protected area of the server and a `post-receive` hook that checks out the contents and systematically copies over certain files into a `public_html` folder. (Inspired by [this tutorial](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto))

I got tired of modifying the `post-receive` hook manually on the server, so my `post-receive` hook now actually copies over a new version of itself from the repo:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf ~/../protected/*
GIT_WORK_TREE=~/../protected git checkout -f

# Rewrite over this file with any updates from the post-receive file
cp ~/../protected/post-receive hooks/post-receive

# Delete public_html
# Copy stuff public_html
```

The problem, of course, is that the new `post-receive` hook never gets run. A seemingly simple solution would be merely to push again, but now  everything is already up to date. This is annoying, because it requires me to fake a new commit every time I update the `post-receive` hook. Is there a way to invoke the `post-receive` hook without faking a commit or `ssh`ing in?

### What I tried

```
git push
git push -f
```

Comment: I know this is late, but I came up with another interesting solution because I implement the same deployment mechanism. After the `checkout -f` is complete I use `rm -rf ~/repo.git/refs/heads/master`. This will delete the master branch, allowing for a push every time.

Answer (score 71):

## Use '--allow-empty'

After the initial push replacing the script, you can do this :

```
git commit --allow-empty -m 'push to execute post-receive'
```

The `--allow-empty` flag overrides git's default behavior of preventing you from making a commit when there are no changes.

**Use an alias and make your life even easier**

Add the following to `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    pushpr = "!f() { git push origin master;git commit --allow-empty -m 'push to execute post-receive';git push origin master; }; f"
```

**Now Just do `git pushpr`**

```
git pushpr
```

This will push any changes to master, which in your case will trigger your post receive replacement script, then it will push again (using the `--allow-empty` flag) which will then execute your updated `post-receive` script.

Comment: If you don’t want to have the extra commit, you can combine `--allow-empty` with `--amend` and `-m The message from the last commit`, but caution: that will rewrite the history of the last commit. Don’t use unless you’re the only developer. You’ll have to force push the next time.

Comment: @Andrew You can run `git commit --allow-empty --amend --no-edit` to reuse the commit message without retyping it or opening an editor.

Comment: @trdarr oh, amazing. I'm totally making an alias for that.

Comment: @thomasd good advice. With `--amend --no-edit` you don't need `--allow-empty` anymore.

Comment: Note: This will create a new commit in the history. So it's basically a convenient way to fake a commit. Something the question author does not want.

Answer (score 25):

I know this probably going to be considered "dangerous" but I like to live on the edge.

I just delete the remote branch and then push it again. Make sure your local branch is up-to-date first to limit the chance of losing stuff.

So if I want to trigger post-receive, in my case to get the testing branch to provision, all I do is:

```
$ git push origin :testing
$ git push origin testing
```

Don't accept this as the answer though.  It's more of a just FYI thing.

Comment: This is actually handy, if it's really just a read-only remote.

Comment: Great for _bare_ git repos, heroku-style

Comment: You will need to run `git config receive.denyDeleteCurrent false` to be able to delete the remote branch though

Answer (score 17):

If you want to avoid making a fake *new* commit, you can simply use

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

This will modify the last commit record and you will be able to use `git push -f` (assuming from your answer that you're fine with the overwrite).

- **convenient:** it doesn't create an extra commit
- **good:** it doesn't use explicit path for the hook in the remote repo
- **bad:** you overwrite history, which is fine in your use case, but shouldn't be used in a shared repository

---

I use this command relatively often to fix something in the last commit  before pushing, so I made an alias for it:

```
git config --global alias.amend 'commit --amend --no-edit'
```

Now I can use it directly for the use case as yours (`git amend`), or

- to add (all) modified files to the last commit: `git amend -a`
- to modify the message: `git amend -m 'better message'`

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a lot of hassle :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad my answer is still useful among the others.

Answer (score 13):

I'm afraid you have to ssh to the server and run the hook script manually. `git push` doesn't make the server run the *pre-push*, *pre-receive* and *post-receive* hooks if there was nothing added (i.e. when git prints *Everything up-to-date*).

The rest of the answer is about version-tracking the *post-receive* hook, so you can modify it without sshing to the server.

Add a shell script named `do-post-receive` to the local repository:

```
$ ls -ld .git
$ echo 'echo "Hello, World!"' >do-post-receive
$ git add do-post-receive
$ git commit do-post-receive -m 'added do-post-receive'
```

Replace your `hooks/post-receive` hook on the server with:

```
#! /bin/sh
while read OLDID NEWID BRANCH; do
  test "$BRANCH" = refs/heads/master && eval "$(git show master:do-post-receive)"
done
```

(Make sure to `chmod 755 hooks/post-receive` on the server.)

Push your changes from the local repository to the server, and watch your `do-post-receive` code run:

```
$ git push origin master
...
remote: Hello, World!
...
```

Comment: Very clever! Unfortunately I may not be able to try this out for awhile to give the accept... But be patient with me.

Comment: Sounds promising, more than my answer anyway. +1

Comment: This did not work at all for me.  I think you'd be better off clearing out the changes every time and doing a full repository push instead.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work, and none of the pre-push, pre-receive or post-receive hooks are run on the server if there are no changes.

Comment: You're almost there!  The problem is that the post-receive script is run with a --censored-- *pipe* as its standard input, so having read the input with `while read ...` there's little or nothing left for the `do-post-receive` script to read.  (I wrote a thing called `git_xhook` that allowed multiple, extended hooks; it's too big for this comment, but this could get you there.)

Comment: I've added an uncoditional `echo` to the hook, and nothing was printed, only *Everything up-to-date*.

Answer (score 5):

In my case i login into remote and run:

`$ sh project.git/hooks/post-receive`

works fine!

Answer (score 4):

Post-receive is the wrong place for artificial command responses.

You want your server-side goodies in the pre-receive exit, dependent on the updated ref -- do e.g. `git update-ref refs/commands/update-hooks @` on the server, then you can e.g. `git push server +@:commands/update-hooks`, and in the server's pre-receive you can

```
while read old new ref; do case $ref in
commands/update-hooks)
        maybe check the incoming commit for authorization
        update hooks here
        echo the results from the update
        denypush=1
        ;;
refs/heads/master)
        extreme vetting on master-branch updates here
        ;;
esac; done

((denypush)) && exit $denypush
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried [empty commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703197/1197775) and [delete upload branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15985535/1197775).

But what about a direct ssh command:

```
ssh your_host /path/to/your_repo/hooks/post-receive
```

Comment: The possible concern with this approach is the environment variables/configurations for your interactive shell login MAY be different from the git push and you may get unexpected behavior.

Comment: if you need to ensure command runs in remot ewith remote env vars maybe `ssh host bash -cl '/path/to/post-receive'`, I am not sure though

Answer (score 3):

I made a bash function to do this. It assumes that you have ssh access can `~/.ssh/config` set accordingly. The default remote is origin

```sh
kick-git() {
    remote="${1:-origin}"
    ssh $(echo $(git remote get-url "$remote")/hooks/post-receive | tr ':' ' ')
}
```

Source and run `kick-git [remote]`

Answer (score 1):

I like Jamie Carl's suggestion but it doesn't work, and I got the error:

> remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.

In my case I'm testing post-receive hooks on my localhost against a bare repository.  Warning/super important, run this command *only* on the **`remote`** server location!

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/develop
```

It'll delete the reference for the develop branch (you may also need to delete any of the files you deployed for that branch too), then you can go ahead and do the `git push deploy_localtest develop` or whatever push command you want for that branch.