# git deploy: force branch switch when everything is up-to-date

Tags: git, deployment

I'm deploying my branches on a test machine with

```
git push branchname
```

On the remote test machine there is a bare repo with a post-receive hook that checkout everything live:

```
checkout -f $branchname
```

always on the same web directory

Everything works fine except that I don't know how to switch branch on the remote.
If the remote repo is on branch dev1 and I do git push dev2, if there are no changes in dev2, git will just say "Everything is up-to-date" and nothing will happen.

I found this solution
[Force git to run post-receive hook, even if everything is "up-to-date"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677125/force-git-to-run-post-recieve-hook-even-if-everything-is-up-to-date)

But it seems to me that it just involves a "dummy" commit each time I want to switch branch.
Any other solution?