# Force push Git Repository even if the contents are up to date

Tags: git

I have a local git repository which I push to some repositories in the "cloud" platform. 
After I do a push using git push origin master, there's a script that gets called at the back-end. The problem is, if the repository is up to date and I try pushing the repo again, it would say that the repo is already up to date and therefore the script never gets called. I want to know if there is a way to re-push the same repo to the same endpoint.

The work-around of changing something in the repo and re-pushing obviously works.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677125/force-git-to-run-post-receive-hook-even-if-everything-is-up-to-date (and the consensus is that you cannot truly repush the same repo)

Comment: Presumably that means the post-receive hook is only one possible reason to trigger this script. In which case it would make sense to have another way to trigger it e.g. SSH or a web request.

Comment: @Guarav Did any of the solutions below work for you?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: I was looking for simple way to achieve this. Using empty commit would work for me. I'll probably create an alias so that the command remains short. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To trigger your pipeline you can submit an empty commit. To do this, can use the **--allow-empty** option when creating your commit.

```
$ git commit -m 'Triggering pipeline' --allow-empty
```

Reference:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Answer (score 0):

If you want a receive/update hook to run even without changing a particular ref, you'll have to either do something like jiggling it with an empty commit as @UnbearableLightness says or use a proxy ref and have the hook know what to do with updates to that ref.  I use this to run arbitrary commands on protected repos, I just push the script to refs/commands and the hook runs it.  You can have a `refs/proxy/*` pattern and trigger the same back-end process an update to the `proxy/`-less ref would.  Maybe even refuse the `refs/proxy/heads/master` push with a "okay, I pretended refs/heads/master was updated" message.